# Gstreamer issue with adding timeoverlay on RTMP stream

Tags: gstreamer, nvidia-jetson-nano

I needed to add a time overlay to an rtmp stream, and save to disk. The following pipeline, without the overlay, works fine:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v \
rtmpsrc location=rtmp://192.168.x.x/live/0 do-timestamp=true ! queue2 ! flvdemux name=demux \
flvmux name=mux \
demux.video ! queue ! decodebin \
    ! nvvidconv \
    ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),width=1920,height=1080, format=(string)I420, framerate=50/1' \
    ! nvv4l2h264enc ! h264parse \
    ! mux.video \
demux.audio ! queue name="dmx_aud_q" ! mux.audio \
mux.src ! queue name="mux_q" ! filesink location="rtmp.flv"
```

Once I add the timeoverlay (or even clockoverlay), the pipeline doesn't run:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v \
rtmpsrc location=rtmp://192.168.0.168/x.x do-timestamp=true ! queue2 ! flvdemux name=demux \
flvmux name=mux \
demux.video ! queue ! decodebin \
    ! timeoverlay \
    ! nvvidconv \
    ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),width=1920,height=1080, format=(string)I420, framerate=50/1' \
    ! nvv4l2h264enc ! h264parse \
    ! mux.video \
demux.audio ! queue name="dmx_aud_q" ! mux.audio \
mux.src ! queue name="mux_q" ! filesink location="rtmp.flv"
```

The GST_DEBUG=3 logs are as added at the end. The Pipeline graph is as below.

[image: Failed Pipeline for Adding Overlay to RTMP stream]

From what I understand, at the point where the `decodebin` hands over to `timeoverlay`, there is some issue with caps negotiation. I'm not able to figure out how to make timeoverlay accept or output data in a way that the pipeline can continue to mux. Any help to understand what is happening here, and how to find a solution, would be great.

This is on an Nvidia Jetson Nano board, running Ubuntu 18.0. (The plugins starting with "nv" can usually be replaced with regular ones on other systems, I believe - `nvvidconv` with `videoconvert`, `nvv4l2h264enc` with `omxh264enc` etc.

> Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
>   Opening in BLOCKING MODE  0:00:00.119491546   834   0x55b9d05600 WARN 
>   v4l2
>   gstv4l2object.c:2370:gst_v4l2_object_add_interlace_mode:0x55b9cf2360
>   Failed to determine interlace mode 0:00:00.119570298   834
>   0x55b9d05600 WARN                    v4l2
>   gstv4l2object.c:2370:gst_v4l2_object_add_interlace_mode:0x55b9cf2360
>   Failed to determine interlace mode 0:00:00.119623164   834
>   0x55b9d05600 WARN                    v4l2
>   gstv4l2object.c:2370:gst_v4l2_object_add_interlace_mode:0x55b9cf2360
>   Failed to determine interlace mode 0:00:00.119721552   834
>   0x55b9d05600 WARN                    v4l2
>   gstv4l2object.c:4408:gst_v4l2_object_probe_caps:
>   Failed to probe pixel aspect ratio with VIDIOC_CROPCAP: Unknown error
>   -1 Pipeline is PREROLLING ... 0:00:00.406155973   834   0x55b9a72370 WARN                flvdemux
>   gstflvdemux.c:659:gst_flv_demux_parse_tag_script: failed
>   reading a tag, skipping
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQueue:dmx_aud_q.GstPad:sink: caps =
>   audio/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)4, framed=(boolean)true,
>   stream-format=(string)raw, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2,
>   codec_data=(buffer)1210
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQueue:dmx_aud_q.GstPad:src: caps =
>   audio/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)4, framed=(boolean)true,
>   stream-format=(string)raw, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2,
>   codec_data=(buffer)1210
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFlvMux:mux.GstFlvMuxPad:sink_1: caps =
>   audio/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)4, framed=(boolean)true,
>   stream-format=(string)raw, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2,
>   codec_data=(buffer)1210
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQueue:queue0.GstPad:sink: caps =
>   video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, width=(int)1920,
>   height=(int)1080,
>   codec_data=(buffer)0142002affe100166742002a95a81e0089f961000003000100000300648401000468ce3c80
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQueue:queue0.GstPad:src: caps =
>   video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, width=(int)1920,
>   height=(int)1080,
>   codec_data=(buffer)0142002affe100166742002a95a81e0089f961000003000100000300648401000468ce3c80
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0.GstGhostPad:sink.GstProxyPad:proxypad0:
>   caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, width=(int)1920,
>   height=(int)1080,
>   codec_data=(buffer)0142002affe100166742002a95a81e0089f961000003000100000300648401000468ce3c80
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:src:
>   caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, width=(int)1920,
>   height=(int)1080,
>   codec_data=(buffer)0142002affe100166742002a95a81e0089f961000003000100000300648401000468ce3c80
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstH264Parse:h264parse1.GstPad:sink:
>   caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, width=(int)1920,
>   height=(int)1080,
>   codec_data=(buffer)0142002affe100166742002a95a81e0089f961000003000100000300648401000468ce3c80
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:sink:
>   caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, width=(int)1920,
>   height=(int)1080,
>   codec_data=(buffer)0142002affe100166742002a95a81e0089f961000003000100000300648401000468ce3c80
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0.GstGhostPad:sink: caps
>   = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080,
>   codec_data=(buffer)0142002affe100166742002a95a81e0089f961000003000100000300648401000468ce3c80
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstH264Parse:h264parse1.GstPad:src:
>   caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream,
>   width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)50/1,
>   interlace-mode=(string)progressive, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0,
>   bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8,
>   parsed=(boolean)true, alignment=(string)au, profile=(string)baseline,
>   level=(string)4.2 Opening in BLOCKING MODE  0:00:00.823485062   834
>   0x55b9ce8a30 WARN                    v4l2
>   gstv4l2object.c:4408:gst_v4l2_object_probe_caps:
>   Failed to probe pixel aspect ratio with VIDIOC_CROPCAP: Unknown error
>   -1 0:00:00.823543397   834   0x55b9ce8a30 WARN                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:2370:gst_v4l2_object_add_interlace_mode:0x7f6807a640
>   Failed to determine interlace mode NvMMLiteOpen : Block : BlockType =
>   261  NVMEDIA: Reading vendor.tegra.display-size : status: 6 
>   NvMMLiteBlockCreate : Block : BlockType = 261 
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/nvv4l2decoder:nvv4l2decoder0.GstPad:sink:
>   caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream,
>   width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)50/1,
>   interlace-mode=(string)progressive, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0,
>   bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8,
>   parsed=(boolean)true, alignment=(string)au, profile=(string)baseline,
>   level=(string)4.2
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter1.GstPad:src:
>   caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream,
>   width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)50/1,
>   interlace-mode=(string)progressive, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0,
>   bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8,
>   parsed=(boolean)true, alignment=(string)au, profile=(string)baseline,
>   level=(string)4.2
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter1.GstPad:sink:
>   caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream,
>   width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)50/1,
>   interlace-mode=(string)progressive, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0,
>   bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8,
>   parsed=(boolean)true, alignment=(string)au, profile=(string)baseline,
>   level=(string)4.2 0:00:00.932089228   834   0x55b9ce8a30 WARN
>   v4l2
>   gstv4l2object.c:4408:gst_v4l2_object_probe_caps:
>   Failed to probe pixel aspect ratio with VIDIOC_CROPCAP: Unknown error
>   -1 0:00:00.932560124   834   0x55b9ce8a30 WARN                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:2370:gst_v4l2_object_add_interlace_mode:0x7f6807a640
>   Failed to determine interlace mode
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/nvv4l2decoder:nvv4l2decoder0.GstPad:src:
>   caps = video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), format=(string)NV12, width=(int)1920,
>   height=(int)1080, interlace-mode=(string)progressive,
>   multiview-mode=(string)mono,
>   multiview-flags=(GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet)0:ffffffff:/right-view-first/left-flipped/left-flopped/right-flipped/right-flopped/half-aspect/mixed-mono,
>   pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2,
>   colorimetry=(string)bt709, framerate=(fraction)50/1
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.065:
>   gst_mini_object_copy: assertion 'mini_object != NULL' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.066:
>   gst_caps_get_structure: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.066:
>   gst_structure_copy: assertion 'structure != NULL' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.066:
>   gst_caps_append_structure_full: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.066:
>   gst_caps_get_structure: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.066:
>   gst_structure_copy: assertion 'structure != NULL' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.067:
>   gst_caps_append_structure_full: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.067:
>   gst_mini_object_copy: assertion 'mini_object != NULL' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.068:
>   gst_caps_get_structure: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.068:
>   gst_structure_copy: assertion 'structure != NULL' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.068:
>   gst_caps_append_structure_full: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.068:
>   gst_caps_get_structure: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.068:
>   gst_structure_copy: assertion 'structure != NULL' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.069:
>   gst_caps_append_structure_full: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed
>   0:00:00.942959420   834   0x55b9ce8a30 WARN                GST_PADS
>   gstpad.c:4226:gst_pad_peer_query: could not send
>   sticky events 0:00:00.943568965   834   0x55b9ce8a30 WARN
>   v4l2videodec
>   gstv4l2videodec.c:1433:gst_v4l2_video_dec_decide_allocation:
>   Duration invalid, not setting latency 0:00:00.944316482   834
>   0x55b9ce8a30 WARN          v4l2bufferpool
>   gstv4l2bufferpool.c:1054:gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_start:
>   Uncertain or not enough buffers, enabling copy threshold
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.073:
>   gst_mini_object_copy: assertion 'mini_object != NULL' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.074:
>   gst_caps_get_structure: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.074:
>   gst_structure_copy: assertion 'structure != NULL' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.074:
>   gst_caps_append_structure_full: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.074:
>   gst_caps_get_structure: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.074:
>   gst_structure_copy: assertion 'structure != NULL' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.074:
>   gst_caps_append_structure_full: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed
>   0:00:00.948613871   834   0x55b9ce8a30 WARN           basetransform
>   gstbasetransform.c:1355:gst_base_transform_setcaps:
>   transform could not transform video/x-h264,
>   stream-format=(string)byte-stream, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080,
>   framerate=(fraction)50/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive,
>   chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8,
>   bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, parsed=(boolean)true, alignment=(string)au,
>   profile=(string)baseline, level=(string)4.2 in anything we support
>   0:00:00.948674601   834   0x55b9ce8a30 WARN           basetransform
>   gstbasetransform.c:1415:gst_base_transform_reconfigure:
>   warning: not negotiated 0:00:00.948709446   834   0x55b9ce8a30 WARN
>   basetransform
>   gstbasetransform.c:1415:gst_base_transform_reconfigure:
>   warning: not negotiated WARNING: from element
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter1:
>   not negotiated Additional debug info: gstbasetransform.c(1415):
>   gst_base_transform_reconfigure ():
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter1:
>   not negotiated 0:00:00.971426937   834   0x7f70004a80 WARN
>   basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3055:gst_base_src_loop: error: Internal
>   data stream error. 0:00:00.971545793   834   0x7f70004a80 WARN
>   basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3055:gst_base_src_loop: error:
>   streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4) 0:00:00.978535326   834 
>   0x7f6807c8f0 WARN          v4l2bufferpool
>   gstv4l2bufferpool.c:1518:gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_dqbuf:
>   Driver should never set v4l2_buffer.field to ANY
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.105:
>   gst_mini_object_copy: assertion 'mini_object != NULL' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.105:
>   gst_caps_get_structure: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.105:
>   gst_structure_copy: assertion 'structure != NULL' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.105:
>   gst_caps_append_structure_full: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.105:
>   gst_caps_get_structure: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.105:
>   gst_structure_copy: assertion 'structure != NULL' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.105:
>   gst_caps_append_structure_full: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.106:
>   gst_mini_object_copy: assertion 'mini_object != NULL' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.106:
>   gst_caps_get_structure: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.106:
>   gst_structure_copy: assertion 'structure != NULL' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.106:
>   gst_caps_append_structure_full: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.106:
>   gst_caps_get_structure: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.106:
>   gst_structure_copy: assertion 'structure != NULL' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.106:
>   gst_caps_append_structure_full: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed
>   ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTMPSrc:rtmpsrc0:
>   Internal data stream error.
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.106:
>   gst_mini_object_copy: assertion 'mini_object != NULL' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.106:
>   gst_caps_get_structure: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.106:
>   gst_structure_copy: assertion 'structure != NULL' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.106:
>   gst_caps_append_structure_full: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.107:
>   gst_caps_get_structure: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.107:
>   gst_structure_copy: assertion 'structure != NULL' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.107:
>   gst_caps_append_structure_full: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed
>   Additional debug info: gstbasesrc.c(3055): gst_base_src_loop ():
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTMPSrc:rtmpsrc0: streaming stopped, reason
>   not-negotiated (-4) ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll. Setting
>   pipeline to NULL ...
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.107:
>   gst_mini_object_copy: assertion 'mini_object != NULL' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.108:
>   gst_caps_get_structure: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.108:
>   gst_structure_copy: assertion 'structure != NULL' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.108:
>   gst_caps_append_structure_full: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.108:
>   gst_caps_get_structure: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.108:
>   gst_structure_copy: assertion 'structure != NULL' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.108:
>   gst_caps_append_structure_full: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.108:
>   gst_mini_object_copy: assertion 'mini_object != NULL' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.108:
>   gst_caps_get_structure: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.108:
>   gst_structure_copy: assertion 'structure != NULL' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.108:
>   gst_caps_append_structure_full: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.108:
>   gst_caps_get_structure: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.109:
>   gst_structure_copy: assertion 'structure != NULL' failed
>
> (gst-launch-1.0:834): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:19:35.109:
>   gst_caps_append_structure_full: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed
>   Freeing pipeline ...

Comment: You can check caps negotiation with `GST_DEBUG=GST_CAPS:5`. Shot in a dark - isnt the problem that nvv4l2decoder produces DMA buffers, but timeoverlay works with just normal buffers? I guess there is no such thing as nvtimeoverlay . What happens when you add videoconvert before the timeoverlay (but I guess you would loose the DMA stuff)?

Comment: Hello @nayana, thanks for the response. You guessed correctly, that is indeed how I ended up solving it - even though timeoverlay source caps say ANY, it cannot handle NVVM memory. `decodebin` uses `nvv4l2decoder` internally, which produces `'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM)'` on it's src. I added an `nvvidconv ! 'video/x-raw'` before the `timeoverlay`, and it works now.

Can you please add it as an answer here, so that I can accept it as an answer?

Comment: I've got some idea.. what about using the nvcompositor to do the composition of your decoded video and timeoverlay and that way it may be faster? The timeoverlay should produce the full screen frames with alpha.. I have no idea if it indeed speeds up things somehow. Maybe it will just be overcomplicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as Aswin said, it was solved by adding convert before timeoverlay.
Its because timeoverlay cannot work with DMA buffers (thats the `(memory:NVMM)` means)
So the pipeline looks like original except for this change:

```
... decodebin ! nvvidconv ! 'video/x-raw' !  timeoverlay ! nvvidconv ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM)
```

The errors are basicaly about timeoverlay not being able to link to nvv4l2decoder which outputs the buffers as DMA. We need nvvidconv to copy those buffers so we can work with them in user space.

Longer explanation with details:

With my faint understanding of DMA/CPU buffers (please correct)- all nv* elements are able to work with DMA buffers (more directly I guess) which speeds up the process. But between `nvv4l2decoder` and `nvv4l2h264enc` we put the timeoverlay to add time into the video..

But unfortunately timeoverlay element does not have ability to work with those buffers. So we added the nvviddonv which slowly copies the buffers (it goes through CPU) into user space, slowly we do the changes, and then it slowly goes back to the faster "DMA buffer space". But I dont see some way around this. Unless there is some fancy custom element that could work with the buffers directly.

There was some work in GStreamer to better work with these buffers in past few years - I saw some presentations by ndufresne about DMA fences (working with DMA buffers asynchronosely) and zero copy pipelines (not sure if it applies):
Zero copy: https://youtu.be/kNaa1fPv_uo
DMA fences: https://youtu.be/HpmzJGHqObs

Some general Linux article:
https://01.org/linuxgraphics/gfx-docs/drm/driver-api/dma-buf.html